# Term clarification: Establishing a domination

Tags: algorithms, terminology, approximation, packing

In the book "Approximation Algorithms" by Vazirani (legally [available online](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/fac/Vijay.Vazirani/book.pdf)), part of the hint to Exercise 9.6 (on page 77 of the book, page 95 of the PDF) says "Establish a domination". I've never heard this terminology before in the context of computer science/approximation algorithms/bin packing (I'm not so sure what the correct context is).

Perhaps someone here has familiarity with this terminology. If so, I'd love to hear the definition of "Domination" in this context.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with translation to me.

Comment: @Raphael I doubt any translation was involved.

Answer (score 1):

We say that $A$ *dominates* $B$ if $A \geq B$ (or, more generally, if $A \succeq B$ in some partial order). To establish a domination means to establish that something dominates something else. I'll let you figure out which domination is meant in your context.